# Passing a setting to an NUnit test when running it from code?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am creating a small web application which will sit within a larger CMS system. The purpose of this application is to validate a spreadsheet which is uploaded and used by another part of the application.

I have written some tests to validate the sheet while I was doing development and planned to reuse the tests as the validator. I can run the tests from code but I can't figure out a way to pass the location of the uploaded spreadsheet to the unit tests.

Here's the code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            if(SpreadsheetFile.HasFile)
            {
                string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".xlsm";
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + newFileName);

                //TODO: how do I pass this in?
                SpreadsheetFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
                CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();

                TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage("Test");
                testPackage.Assemblies.Add(Server.MapPath("~/bin/Redacted.Tests.dll"));
                //testPackage.Settings["spreadsheet"] = path;

                TestSuiteBuilder builder = new TestSuiteBuilder();
                TestFilter filter = new NameFilter( new TestName() { Name = "RedactedTests" } );
                TestSuite suite = builder.Build(testPackage);
                TestResult testResult = suite.Run( new NullListener(), filter );

                rptResults.DataSource = testResult.Results;
                rptResults.DataBind();

                if (testResult.IsSuccess)
                {
                    ResultPlaceHolder.Text = "<span class=\"success\">Upload succeeded and all tests passed.</span>";
                }
                else
                {
                    ResultPlaceHolder.Text = "<span class=\"fail\">Upload succeeded but tests failed.</span>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ResultPlaceHolder.Text = "<span class=\"fail\">Upload failed.</span>";
            }


        }
     }
}
```

I was thinking about writing out an appsetting dynamically?
Am I doing it wrong?

**Edit**: To clarify things a bit. The above code snippet is an ASPX code behind from a WebForm. SpreadSheetFile is an asp:FileUpload control. The unit tests being run are more integration tests as they do operate on a physical spreadsheet. In my testing, I copy this from App_Data (where the spreadsheet lives in svn) into a directory that the unit test can access.

The requirements are that I provide a mechanism to validate the spreadsheet and then update it within the other web app. So I thought I could reuse the tests, but it's not looking good!

Comment: I don't understand. A unit test should be run stand-alone. It should definitely not contain business logic. It should *test* business logic. So running a unit test code from application code is the world upside-down. Or am I completely lost now?

Comment: It doesn't contain business logic necessarily. I was just trying to reuse my unit tests as validation. The actual business logic is still in the class being testing. I just want to leverage those tests to make sure this spreadsheet is going to work with my business logic.

Comment: So your code snippet is part of a class in your domain (if that). A unit test would typically call this method with a mock spreadsheet object, not a downloaded one. So your method should have a parameter to enter a spreadsheet. But I'm a bit running blind here, because I don't know the origin and state of `SpreadsheetFile` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No this is a code behind file from an ASPX page. This part of the application doesn't really deal with the domain, all it is concerned with is checking if an uploaded Excel spreadsheet contains some named ranges etc. SpreadsheetFile is a ASPX FormUpload control. 

I have written integration tests in NUnit while writing my business logic - I didn't see the point of mocking the excel file as it is core to the business logic (in fact it is the business logic, please don't focus on this).